# Fingerprint unlock and password multiple-attempt security

Tags: security, encryption, password, fingerprint

I have noticed that fingerprint unlocking on Android is pretty insecure. If you make 5 failed attempts (which is quite a lot), the phone just disables the scanner for 30 seconds and then re-enables it. I would like to reduce the number of attempts before disabling the scanner, and then set it to require the password before unlocking. Google searches for this have revealed many pages of results of people wanting to make their phones *less* secure by increasing the number of attempts or disabling the horrific 30 second waiting period, but am I the only one concerned that it is pretty insecure as it is? I don't want to have to disable fingerprint unlock, as I have a very secure password set that would be a bit of a pain to enter every time I unlocked my phone.

Likewise with passwords, the "Automatically wipe after x failed password attempts" option seems to have disappeared from my phone as of the Oreo update, and there is a fixed 30 second waiting period every 5 attempts, which means that with a reasonable pool of guesses, anyone could brute force my password with enough tries.

What can I do to make my phone more secure?

Comment: Certainly not an answer, but in lieu of achieving middling security via a long password plus the fingerprint option, you could potentially disable the fingerprint altogether and use a more manageable password.